# Что означает Environment="TERM=dumb" в секции [Service] файла сервиса systemd?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, systemd

Что означает выражение 'Environment="TERM=dumb"' в секции [Service] файла сервиса systemd? Особенно интересно, что делает присвоение "TERM=dumb".

Comment: устанавливает переменную среды `TERM` в  значение `dumb`, очевидно... «зачем?» — лучше спросить у того, кто  писал модуль или хотя бы привести контекст...

Comment: [ссылка](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent) это описано вот здесь, но я так и не понял зачем? Type=idle - понятно systemd будет задерживать выполнение бинарного файла службы, пока не будут выпонены все остальные задания. А вот строка ниже нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environment="TERM=dumb"` устанавливает переменную среды `TERM` в значение `dumb` при запуске скрипта.

«Зачем это сделано [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent)?» — лучше спросить у автора, я могу выдвинуть несколько догадок:

- т.к. `powertop` — консольная утилита, использующая curses, так что вероятно, автор переживал, что она может форматировать свой вывод или попробовать захватить терминал в зависимости от значения `TERM` и поэтому присвоил ей невалидное значение.
- или может `powertop` просто отказывался работать без установки `TERM`.
- или автор просто бездумно скопировал эту строчку из другого модуля и здесь она ни на что не влияет и вообще не нужна.

В любом случае, вполне возможно, что эта строчка не является абсолютно необходимой...